# R: Remove -Inf and Inf from a vector

Tags: r

I can remove na values from a vector:

```
na.omit(c(1,2,NA,3))
```

But how can I remove Inf and -Inf?

```
na.omit(c(1,2,NA,3,Inf))
na.omit(c(1,2,NA,3,-Inf))
```

Comment: See `is.finite` and `is.infinite`.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/15393251/680068

Comment: Thanks that's great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that `is.na` and `is.infinite` may operate on vectors, returning vectors of booleans. So you can filter the vector as so:

```
> x <- c(1, 2, NA, Inf, -Inf)
> x[!is.na(x) & !is.infinite(x)]
[1] 1 2
```

If this needs to be done inline, consider putting the above in a function.